# how can I find and replace the string with quote?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

how can I find replace the string with the quote ?

Input file:-

```
cat test.conf
DIR='/mnt/'
```

I would like to replace the variable NEWDIR, the variable could be "/opt" or "/mnt/iso"

Note:- also single quote in the input file should be maintained.

```
NEWDIR="/opt/"
sed -i 's/^DIR=.*$/DIR=$NEWDIR/' test.conf
```

but it doesn't seem to be replacing the string

```
cat test.conf
DIR='/mnt/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
NEWDIR=/mnt/
sed -i'' "s:^DIR=.*$:DIR='$NEWDIR':g" test.conf
```

Changes to the OP code:

- Use `:` for sed's delimiter to avoid escaping slashes in `NEWDIR`
- Use `sed "..."` instead of `sed '...'` to allow parameter expansion

test it with a here-string:

```
$ NEWDIR=/mnt/
$ sed "s:^DIR=.*$:DIR='$NEWDIR':g" <<< "DIR='/opt/'"
DIR='/mnt/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
var="/opt"  ##A shell variable.
awk -v s1="\"" -v value="$var" '{gsub(/\047\/mnt\/\047/,s1 value s1)} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself use:

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v value="$var" '{gsub(/\047\/mnt\/\047/,s1 value s1)} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes
your looks will be like this

```
sed -i "s/^DIR=.*$/DIR=$NEWDIR/" test.conf
```